# Understanding HTML5 pushState and server-side interaction

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pushstate

I am trying to understand something fundamental. I have an AngularJS front-end with a Rails backend. Whenever I define a route on the Angular side of things, it still hits the Rails backend, even if the route is defined on Angular. Is this the correct behavior for pushState? Or does it mean that I do not have pushState properly configured on the client? Should the requests not be going out to the server unless a route that's not matched by Angular is hit?

This is what I am currently using to 'enable' pushState with AngularJS:

```
App.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Not sure if that's not proper or if my understanding of pushState is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Any url you have will always hit the server on the first request. HTML5 pushState is an API for updating the displayed url and the browser history.

As such, if your Angular app is properly handling routes, you can configure your Rails controllers to bootstrap your app with the requisite JSON data and handle rendering of the UI on the client side.

Here's a snippet from a simple rails/backbone app's routes.rb:

```
resources :pages, except: :show
get ':id/:model', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
get ':id', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
get '', to: 'pages#show'
```

The deep linking is then handled by the clientside pushState router.

Comment: It's worth noting that these routes are particular to the app I was working on, but essentially they allow the server to render the pages#show action for any route that matches the above pattern and my controller/view bootstrap the app and my clientside framework (in my case backbone, in your's: angular) instantiates the app and handles the rendering logic based on the url.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure you backend to server `index` page on any request `/*` (of course you could namespace these route handlers to serve as api endpoints etc.)

So, when you hit `/some-page` on the browser, you server will serve `index` page from where your `ember` router will render the right view.

If you want the server to also handle and render different routes, then you should configure ajax requests to use some special `header` that is handled appropriately on the server.

Simply saying, on the server if you see a request with that special header, then you render your page on the backend... for everything else, you server `index` page.

I'm not familiar with ember and rails, but I've done the same thing with backbone and node.